# zsh: read until EOF instead of new line

Tags: zsh

how can I complete the following code in zsh using `read` builtin to collect the lines of output

```
ls -l |
{
   read total ; 
   IFS=$'\n' read -dX -A lines  # <-- what should be the delimiter to denote EOF
}
```

Specifically, `ls -l` will first print a line `total nnn` which should be read into `$total`. All the following lines should be collected into an array `$lines`.

What should I specify as EOF (to be put in the place of `X`)? My application is actually more complicated. So please do not suggest using `while` to read line by line and append into the array.

Comment: `lines=$(cat)`?

Comment: @JanHudec but as I know, command substitution cannot read the stdin pipped from `ls -l`. If you know how to, then it serves as an answer

Comment: in `bash`, there is `mapfile`

Comment: Command substitution can't, but the `cat` command can and you can use it command substitution (and I mean I just tried and it works here)

Comment: do you mean to replace the line `IFS=...` to `lines=$(cat)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: yes, it works. But I don't know the reason.  Actually, `ls | x=$(cat)` doesn't work while `ls | { x=$(cat) }` works.  Where is the stdin of the command substitution connected to. Do you mind to explain this and put them in the answer? I will then accept it the answer. Thanks

Comment: Hm, something in the pipeline setup breaks the stdin assignment; when you add the `{}`, you force the assignment to be done in subshell, which then works.

Comment: Subshell? Braces should not create subshell

Comment: No, braces do not create a subshell. However, they force the subprocess created for the pipeline step to be one. Whenever you have `foo | bar`, the shell has to fork a subprocess to run `bar`. When `bar` is a structured command, it will be completely processed in that subprocess (so it is a full subshell), but when `bar` is  a simple command, the shell apparently takes some shortcut that makes stdin inaccessible to the processes in command substitution.
(Note: I am analysing the observed behaviour of zsh; I am not sure what was actually intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use

```
ls -l | {
read total;
lines=(${(f)"$(cat)"})
}
```

explanation:

1. `"$(cat)"` turn the remainder lines into a string containing newlines
2. `${(f)...}` will split the string at newlines
3. the outermost `(...)` creates an array